# warning C4127: conditional expression is constant

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, conditional-statements, compiler-warnings

```
#define VALUE_MAX 300
int main() {
   if(VALUE_MAX)
      printf("The value is %d",VALUE_MAX);
   return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the above program `if(VALUE_MAX)` is showing a warning

> conditional expression is constant.

How to solve the above warning?

Comment: "_How to solve the above warning?_" -- Remove the `if`.

Comment: `#pragma warning(disable:4127)`

Answer (score 3):

since the if condition becomes always true that is a constant ...

```
int main()
 {
// if(VALUE_MAX)
#ifdef VALUE_MAX
 printf("The value is %d",VALUE_MAX);
#endif
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This will fail if one day, someone changed VALUE_MAX from 300 to 0.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `VALUE_MAX` is not a variable, it's a MACRO. MACROs can be considered as a *textual replacement* at preprocessing time. So,

```
  if(VALUE_MAX)
```

which is translated to

```
 if (300)
```

is always TRUE. It is equivalent to

```
  if(1)
```

which is having *essentially* no effect. The code block under the `if` condition will execute unconditionally.

---

EDIT: (*Elaboration for better understamding*)

An `if` statement is called a *selection statement*. The syntax of simple `if` statement is

```
 if ( expression ) statement
```

based on the evaluation of `expression`, it is decided whether the following `statement` (or block) will be executed.

In case of your code,

```
  if(VALUE_MAX)
```

**always** evaluates to TRUE. In this scenario, the use of `if` statement is meaningless. YOu can get rid of the `if` statement altogether.

Comment: @user2931858 , The real question is, *why* do you have/need such an `if`? The compiler warns because is is **always** true as mentioned in the answer. It doesn't make sense why there is a condition there which is the reason that the compiler is emitting a warning.

Comment: @user2931858 why you tried `if(1)`? I said that is _ineffective_. :-)

Answer (score 2):

VALUE_MAX is replace with a number therefore the condition is replaced with

```
if(300)
```

which is always true.

ways to get around the warning:

1. change VALUE_MAX to a variable

`int VALUE_MAX = 300;`

2. change the condition to ifdef

`#ifdef VALUE_MAX
    printf("The value is %d",VALUE_MAX);
 #endif`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want a (pre-)compile time macro "if" (`#ifdef`), rather than a runtime "if" (`if (…)`):

```
#define VALUE_MAX 300

int main() {
#ifdef VALUE_MAX
   printf("The value is %d", VALUE_MAX);
#endif
   return 0;
}
```

The code between `#ifdef` and `#endif` will be compiled if you have `#define`d the `VALUE_MAX` macro.

Comment: This will fail if one day, someone changed VALUE_MAX from 300 to 0.